# Why are size of 2D arrays inconsistent in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am java developer at work therefore, not that much familiar with the low level concepts of C. I am trying to create multidimensional array. I have a method for memory allocation, and trying to figure out which strategy I need. So, I used three types of allocation;

```
int **allocarray(int row, int col)
{
        int **array1 = malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = malloc(col * sizeof(int));
        printf("col=%d - Size of array1[%d]=%d (%d)\n", col, i, sizeof(array1[i]), ((int *)(col * sizeof(int))));
    }

    int *array2[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        array2[i] = (int *)malloc(col * sizeof(int));
        printf("col=%d - Size of array2[%d]=%d (%d)\n", col, i, sizeof(array2[i]), ((int *)(col * sizeof(int))));
    }

    int(*array3)[row] = malloc(sizeof(int[row][col]));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < col; ++j)
        {
            array3[i][j] = 1;
            printf("col=%d - Size of array2[%d]=%d (%d)\n", col, i, sizeof(array3[i]), ((int *)(col * sizeof(int))));
        }

    int *data = malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));
    int **array4 = malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        array4[i] = &(data[i * col]);

    printf(" in allocarray(array1); %d - %p mult(%d * %d * %d)\n", sizeof(array1), array1, row, col, sizeof(int));
    printf(" in allocarray(array2); %d - %p mult(%d * %d * %d)\n", sizeof(array2), array2, row, col, sizeof(int));
    printf(" in allocarray(array3); %d - %p mult(%d * %d * %d)\n", sizeof(array3), array3, row, col, sizeof(int));
    printf(" in allocarray(array3); %d - %p mult(%d * %d * %d)\n", sizeof(array4), array4, row, col, sizeof(int));
    return array4;
```

and, here is my main;

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    int N = MATSIZE;
    int K, nOverK;
    // Initialize the MPI environment

    // Get the number of processes

    K = 4;
    nOverK = N / K;

    int **arr = allocarray(nOverK, N);
    printf("after allocarray:: %d\n", sizeof(arr));
    srand(time(NULL) + taskid);
    /*
        * Fulfilling the array with random numbers 
        * */
    for (i = 0; i < nOverK; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = get_random(1);
        }
    }
    print_arr(arr, nOverK, N);
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

When I use array1, I get this output;

```
col=8 - Size of array1[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array1[1]=8 (32)
 in allocarray(array1); 8 - 0x5648db93c2a0 mult(2 * 8 * 4)
after allocarray:: 8
 53  74  75  16  76   0  20  87 
 52  90  82   1  26  81  75  93
```

array2;

```
(Compile warning)
test.c: In function ‘allocarray’:
test.c:105:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
  105 |     return array2;
      |            ^~~~~~

(OUTPUT)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
 in allocarray(array2); 16 - 0x7ffde45e7440 mult(2 * 8 * 4)
after allocarray:: 8
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

array3;

```
(Compile warning)
test.c: In function ‘allocarray’:
test.c:108:12: warning: returning ‘int (*)[(sizetype)(row)]’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘int **’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  108 |     return array3;
      |            ^~~~~~

(OUTPUT)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
 in allocarray(array3); 8 - 0x55c9578222a0 mult(2 * 8 * 4)
after allocarray:: 8
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

array4;

```
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[0]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
col=8 - Size of array2[1]=8 (32)
 in allocarray(array3); 8 - 0x563a3f98a750 mult(2 * 8 * 4)
after allocarray:: 8
 33  43  77  85  67  23  72  26 
 82  24  96  40  62  43  94  75
```

If it is important, next step is to have a parallel matrix multiplication after being able to allocate memory.

So, What am I missing here, and what am I doing wrong to get a segmentation fault? First and last methods that I don't get any error, Why are sizes seen inconsistent? Shouldn't array size be 32 after method call?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sizeof(...)` returns an _unsigned_ type that is `size_t`.  Use `"%zu"` to print it

Comment: Tip: `sizeof(arr)` where `arr` is a pointer returns  **the size of the pointer**, not the size of the allocation. For *any* given `int **arr` the `sizeof()` will be the same.

Comment: Tip: Multi-dimensional arrays are more hassle than they're worth so if you can avoid them you can save a lot of trouble. Just use a singular array and emulate the locations, like `x + y * w` is good for an array of size `h, w`.

Comment: You should also really pay attention to those compiler warnings. It looks like you've invoked undefined behaviour as well.